# Intuitive way of showing a matrix is negative semi-definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For what value of $x$ the following is a negative semi-definite matrix:
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
x & \frac{x}{2}-1 & \frac{x}{2}-1 \\
\frac{x}{2}-1 & x & \frac{x}{2}-1 \\
\frac{x}{2}-1 & \frac{x}{2}-1 & x
\end{bmatrix}
.
$$

---

**My try**

Let $x$ be a real value, $\mathbf{I} \in \mathbb{R}^3$, and $\mathbf{1}^{\top}=[1,1,1]^{\top}$. Then $A$ can be written as follows:
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
x & \frac{x}{2}-1 & \frac{x}{2}-1 \\
\frac{x}{2}-1 & x & \frac{x}{2}-1 \\
\frac{x}{2}-1 & \frac{x}{2}-1 & x
\end{bmatrix}
=(1+\frac{x}{2})\mathbf{I}-(1-\frac{x}{2})\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^{\top}.
$$

**My question**

Is there any way to somehow use the above structure and find the values of $x$ easier without going into determinant or eigenvalues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've rewritten the matrix in the form you've discovered for yourself, you can read off its eigenvalues without doing anything more than trivial algebra.  Any other way of finding out the values of $\ x\ $ for which it's negative semidefinite is likely to be more bothersome, so it's really not worth your while to try to avoid "going into eigenvalues".

Suppose $\ B\ $ is an $\ n\times n\ $ matrix of the form
$$
B= a\mathbf{I}+b\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^\top\ .
$$
If $\ \mathbf{v}\ $ any $\ n\times1\ $ column vector orthogonal to $\ \mathbf{1}\ $ (i.e $\ \mathbf{1}^\top\mathbf{v}=0\ $), then
\begin{align}
B\mathbf{v}&=a\mathbf{v}+b\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^\top\\
&=a\mathbf{v}\ .
\end{align}
Thus $\ \mathbf{v}\ $ is an eigenvector of $\ B\ $ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\ a\ $.  Since the space of vectors orthogonal to $\ \mathbf{1}\ $ has dimension $\ n-1\ $, then $\ a\ $ is an eigenvalue of $\ B\ $ of geometric multiplicity $\ n-1\ $.

Also,
\begin{align}
B\mathbf{1}&=a\mathbf{1}+b\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^\top\mathbf{1}\\
&=(a+nb)\mathbf{1}\ .
\end{align}
Thus $\ \mathbf{1}\ $ is an eigenvector of $\ B\ $ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\ a+nb\ $.

In your case $\ a=\left(1+\frac{x}{2}\right), b=\left(\frac{x}{2}-1\right)\ $ and $\ n=3\ $, so the eigenvalues of $\ A\ $ are $\ \left(1+\frac{x}{2}\right)\ $ and $\ 2(x-1)\ $, and $\ A\ $ will be negative semidefinite if neither of these is greater than zero—that is, if and only if $\ x\le-2\ $.

Comment: @onza leggiera: Can you add your hint as a column and post your solution as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP asked, there is a way to answer this without explicitly looking into the eigenvalues. A matrix $A$ is negative semi-definite if for any vector $q$ we have $q^T A q \leq 0$. Now, let $q = [a,b,c]^T$. Using your decomposition of A this gives us $$(1+x/2)(a^2+b^2+c^2) \leq (1-x/2) (a+b+c)^2.$$

The fun part about this being that both $(a^2+b^2+c^2)$ and $(a+b+c)^2$ are non-negative themselves. Now, observe the signs of $(1+x/2)$ and $(1-x/2)$: for $x < -2$, you have $(1+x/2)<0$ and $(1-x/2)>0$ and hence the inequality is satisfied, regardless of the values of $a, b, c$. Hence for $x\leq-2$, the matrix is always negative semi-definite. With the same reasoning you can argue that for $x\geq 2$ both signs have flipped and hence the matrix is positive semi-definite.

For $x \in (-2,2)$ it is a little harder to argue. Both signs are positive and for some $x$, the inequality can be $<$ or $>$, depending on the values of $a, b, c$ (e.g., for $x=0$ and $q=[1,1,1]$ vs. $q=[1,1,-1]$). So at least for some $x$ in this interval, it will be indefiite. But that goes beyond what was asked anyways.

Comment: How did you get $x\geq 1$?

Comment: That was a mishap, I meant to write $x \geq 2$. I corrected the reply.